# How to make two group factors and change the value in dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

The dataframe looks like

```
x <- rep(c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-02", "2010-01-03", "2010-01-04", "2010-01-05", "2010-01-06","2010-01-07"), 10)
y <- rep(c(1,3), 35)
mydata <- data.frame(x,y)
head(mydata, 3)
           x y
1 2010-01-01 1
2 2010-01-02 3
3 2010-01-03 1
```

By using `as.Date()` and `weekdays()`, I get "Monday", "Tuesday" ...  in a new variable called `$weekday`

```
            x y   weekday
1  2010-01-01 1    Friday
2  2010-01-02 3  Saturday
3  2010-01-03 1    Sunday
```

What I want is make two factor groups:
One is `c_weekday <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Wednesday", "Friday")` 
and another is `c_weekend <- c("Saturday", "Sunday")`

I want to loop `mydata$weekday` and change the values to either `c_weekday` or `c_weekend`
And after this I only have two factors `c_weekday` and `c_weekend` to do some further aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydata$weekday <- ifelse(mydata$weekday %in% c_weekday, "c_weekday", "c_weekend")
```

equivalent to

```
mydata$weekday[mydata$weekday %in% c_weekday] <- "c_weekday"
mydata$weekday[mydata$weekday %in% c_weekend] <- "c_weekend"
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried for() loop and took me a long time. ifelse() is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `%chin%` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[weekday %chin% c_weekday, weekday := "c_weekday"
        ][weekday %chin% c_weekend, weekday := "c_weekend"][]
```